# Combine temporary table of dates with two tables and fill in missing values?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a `rates` table which holds rows of nightly rates **per day**. I have a `ratecodes` table which houses different ratecodes mapped to `rates`.

My goal is to find any missing `rates` for any days for an X period of time. For this example let's use 1 month.

Desired result: 64 rows of which 2 rows are filled with information with the first rate code. The second rate code has absolutely no rows in `rates` but I need to show that it's actually missing dates. ( **64 because 1 month from now returns 32 days x 2 rate codes** )

Two tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `ratecode` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ratecode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `ratecode` VALUES ('1', 'BLAH');
INSERT INTO `ratecode` VALUES ('2', 'NAH');


CREATE TABLE `rates` (
  `thedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ratecode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `rates` VALUES ('2014-12-27', '999', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `rates` VALUES ('2014-12-26', '99', '2', '1');
```

So using this query, in 2 parts. Part 1 is a temporary table of dates from today to 1 month ahead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDates` AS (

SELECT 

CAST((SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) AS date) d

FROM ( SELECT 0 H
    UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300
  ) H CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 T
    UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
    UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
    UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
  ) T CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 U
    UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
    UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
    UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
  ) U

WHERE
  (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) <= (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

ORDER BY d ASC

);
```

And part 2 is the actual selection going on:

```
SELECT
*

FROM
rates


RIGHT JOIN myDates ON ( myDates.d = rates.thedate )
LEFT OUTER JOIN ratecode ON ( rates.ratecode = ratecode.id )
```

This returns only 32 rows back because in `rates`, there are 2 records for the first entry in `ratecode`. I don't get back the 32 missing rows for the other ratecode. How can I adjust in order to retain this information?

After I get the 64 rows back, I also need to filter for which ones are "blank" or haven't been entered in `rates`. So missing values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate all the rows using a `cross join`, then `left join` to the data and filter out all th ematches:

```
select rc.ratecode, d.d as missingdate
from ratecode rc cross join
     mydates d left join
     rates r
     on rc.id = r.ratecode and d.d = r.thedate
where r.id is null;
```

Comment: Just testing - this seems right, let me apply it to my real data and get back to you.

Comment: Testing on the real data it seems to be right, but why does the number of rows differ everytime I run it? One second I get 60~k results, next second same query 70k results. This query is date dynamic but the day hasn't changed yet. Whaat?

Comment: @meder . . . This should consistently return the same number of rows with the same inputs.

Comment: Could it be it's just the database deleting and removing rows concurrently? I can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: @meder . . . That could happen if you have other queries running on the database that are modifying the data.

Comment: http://static.arounds.org/concurrent.png I believe there are concurrent queries running and this causes "duplicates" in the results. One second there are no duplicates when I run it, next second there are. Any easy way to get rid of duplicates like that or want me to open a new q?

Comment: @meder . . . You should probably ask a new question, including more information about the environment where you are running the queries.